# How to get image source instead of image tag in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress and trying to change the code so I can get image source so I could use it in css as background but its generating image

This is the code which is already written in funtions.php

```
$string .= '<p class="recent-image"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 700, 500) ) .'</a></p></div>';
```

after reviewing many post regarding this, I found I can get the image url only by the following code

```
$string .= '<p class="recent-image"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'">' . wp_get_attachment_image_src() .'</a></p></div>';
```

Update this code in my code `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` but nothing generated in result.

Can somebody please suggest what should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`:

```
$string .= '<p class="recent-image"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'">' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, array( 700, 500) ) .'</a></p></div>';
```

If you want to use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`, you also need to pass the post id:

`wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_id)`

```
$string .= '<p class="recent-image"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'">' . wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_id) .'</a></p></div>';
```

You can read the documentation about `wp_get_attachment_image_src` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) where you can see that the first argument passed to this function is the `id` and it is required, not optional, that's why it return nothing like you used it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php get_image_tag( $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ); ?>
```

Comment: An <img src /> tag for an image attachment, scaling it down if requested.

The filter 'get_image_tag_class' allows for changing the class name for the image without having to use regular expressions on the HTML content. The parameters are: what WordPress will use for the class, the Attachment ID, image align value, and the size the image should be.

The second filter 'get_image_tag' has the HTML content, which can then be further manipulated by a plugin to change all attribute values and even HTML content.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.